Testing if the intersection of affine flats and hamming ball is empty
Suppose as input we are given $W = a + V \subset \mathbb{F}_q^n$ where $V$ is a $k$ dimensional vector space. We are specifically given the basis of $V$ and $a$. Moreover we are given $y \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$ and parameter $0\leq\delta\leq n $. Are there efficient algorithm that tests whether $W \cap B(y,\delta)$ is empty or not. Note that $B(y,\delta)$ is the hamming ball of radius $\delta$. Intuitively it feels like an NP-hard problem but I cant locate references that confirms it. Any help would be appreciated!

Even if $a$ is zero, isn't this linear code decoding (which is NP-complete)?
